# Restarting a service on a time interval

Tags: centos, services

How can I set the CentOS to restart a service on a time interval?

Comment: Which version of Centos?  Is the service started from an init script or via systemd or other method?  Does the init script/systemd unit have a "restart" option?

Comment: If it's a regular time interval you can use `cron` if it's a time interval that needs to be determined each time, then you probably want `atd`. systemd has timers but it's probably best to be as systemd-neutral as possible for the time being. There's still a whole lot of RHEL6 and even RHEL 5 out there.

Comment: @StephenHarris i'm using CentOS 7.2

Comment: @Bratchley how can i active the cron?

Comment: You can either add a crontab entry to a user's crontab or add a cron entry to a file in `/etc/cron.daily` or `/etc/cron.hourly`

Comment: You want to do `man cron` and `man crontab`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said before you need a cronjob to make a time-specific event.

It's a bit confusing at the beginning, but here're examples:

**Edit cronjob**

`crontab -e`

**Setting time interval**

min hour day month day of the week /var/www/app/test.sh

**Where**

Note - a day of the week are defined in USA week start in Sunday
/var/www/app/test.sh - Path to the script or command you'll execute in a time manner.

**Here's an example of running by backup script every day at 00:05 only on Saturday AND Sunday:**

`5 0 * * 0-1 /root/scripts/backup/dayly-backup.sh`

With the same command you can restart some service (let's say Apache) everyday at midnight (on Ubuntu):

`5 0 * * * /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

**Remove crontab (will remove all crontabs defined)**

`crontab -r`

**Final notes**

What service you need to restart? Keep in mind that most of the services have special modes for restarting them (without killing the service, otherwise this will cause a data loss).